# difference between migration from svn to bitBucket AND directly importing code to bitBucket

Tags: java, git, svn, bitbucket, entity-framework-migrations

We are planning to move from `SVN` to `GIT` for that we choose bitBucket.

For doing this we have two ways:

1. we can convert / migrate our code from svn to git with the help of bitBucket tutorial.

ELSE

2. we can direclty initialize git code on local machine and upload this code to bitBucket with import command of git.

QUE: **So what will be the difference between this two.**

some queries:
1. if we migrate than previous SVN history of code changes can be viewed on bitBucket?

Answer (score 3):

If you migrate using tutorials you history of commits will be available, if you do directly import svn code to bitbucket commit history will not be available.